# Jython convert a java array how to

Tags: arrays, jython

How can I convert the following code from java to jython?

```
N=200
T=N/5
int[] ranges = int[N] 
Arrays.fill(ranges, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.  It builds an array of N size filled with the value 2.

```
from array import array
N=200
T=N/5
fill = [2] * N
ranges = array('i', fill)
```